# Using node bin/www with twits

Tags: javascript, beginner, node.js, express.js, twitter

I use the following code which is working as expected, but I want to use it in production. I'm not sure that this is clean code since I'm new to node.js. It would be great if I can get some example how can I write cleaner code.

1. I mean how do I use the `config` to read the values, there is better way?
2. How do I use the `onListening`?

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('blog-twitter:server');
var http = require('http');
var os=require('os');
var request=require('superagent')
/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '8062');
app.set('port', port);


/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
//var io=require('express-socket.io');

var server = http.createServer(app);
var io=require('socket.io').listen(server);
var Twitter=require('twitter');
var cfg = require('../config.json');
//console.log(cfg.twitter);
/**
*Create a twitter client to use AUTH credentials defined
*in config.json file
*/
var client=new Twitter({
  consumer_key: cfg.twitter.consumer_key,
  consumer_secret: cfg.twitter.consumer_secret,
  access_token_key: cfg.twitter.access_token_key,
  access_token_secret: cfg.twitter.access_token_secret
});
/**
Bind to twitter public streaming API
*/
var stream=client.stream('statuses/filter',{track:"Javascript"});
/**
*Create twitter stream, when a tweet is available, 
*get its embeded format and emit that to the server.
*/
stream.on("data", function(data){
  console.log(data.id_str);
  var tweet_id="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/oembed.json?id="+data.id_str;
  //console.log(data);

  //console.log("ID:",tweet_id);
  request.get(tweet_id)
  .end(function(err,res){
      if(err){
        console.log("Error: "+err);
      }else{
        //console.log(res.body);
        io.emit('tweet',res.body);
      }
  });
  //console.log("Tweet: ",data);
});
stream.on('error', function(err){
  console.log("Error retrieving tweets: "+err);
});
io.on('connection', function(client){
  client.on("join", function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
  client.emit("join",{"message":"Welcome"});
});
/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var serverName=cfg.server;
  var runServer=`http://localhost:8060/service/tweets/${server.address().port}`;
  if(cfg.hosted){
    runServer=`http://${serverName}/service/tweets/${server.address().port}`;
  }
  console.log(" Server on:",runServer)
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
  var expose=()=>{
      request.put(blogServer,(err,res)=>{
        if(err){
          console.log("Error:",err);
        }
      });
  }
  setInterval(expose,15*1000);
}
```

Comment: If the code is working correctly and complete, the best place would be Code Review. Though you will need to wait for answers longer than here, but generally Code Review is the right place to seek for code improvements for already working and complete code.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write production-ready code using node, then you should use node modules to divide your code into independent, maintainable modules. Even better, use a framework (Express). It provides "development" and "productions" options for the application and it also solves the trivial common issues for you, like setting up a router. You can also use an [scaffolding tool](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html), to generate a standard folder structure for your app.

For reading values from a config file, create a new module and store all the application wide configuration in it, instead of reading directly from a .json file.

Coming to onListening() function, it's not a good practice to hardcode url's. It's better to store them in a config module and require it when needed.